# Evaluate the following integral from $0$ to $\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\int_0^\pi\mathrm{e}^{\left|\cos\left(x\right)\right|}\sin\left(x\right)\left(2\sin\left(\dfrac{\cos\left(x\right)}{2}\right)+3\cos\left(\dfrac{\cos\left(x\right)}{2}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

I first decided to evaluate the indefinite integral and then I will put the limits.

---

Let $u=\cos x$ So our integral becomes $$-\int\mathrm{e}^{|u|}\left(2\sin\left(\dfrac{u}{2}\right)+3\cos\left(\dfrac{u}{2}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}u$$
Let $v=\frac{u}2$  so our integral becomes $$-2\int\mathrm{e}^{2|v|}\left(2\sin\left(v\right)+3\cos\left(v\right)\right)\mathrm{d}v$$ Now applying linearity $$-4\int\mathrm{e}^{2|v|}\sin\left(v\right)\mathrm{d}v-6\int\mathrm{e}^{2|v|}+\cos\left(v\right)\mathrm{d}v$$

---

Now I'm stuck. I can't evaluate those two integrals. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've already done the hard part. To evaluate the integral of a piecewise function like the absolute value, you can just split the integral into pieces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take care also of the limits of integration:
from your work, the given integral $I$ is equal to
$$I=-\int_1^{-1}e^{|u|}\left(2\sin\left(\dfrac{u}{2}\right)+3\cos\left(\dfrac{u}{2}\right)\right)du
=2\int_{-1}^1e^{|u|}\sin\left(\dfrac{u}{2}\right)du
+3\int_{-1}^1e^{|u|}\cos\left(\dfrac{u}{2}\right) du$$
Now the first integrand is an odd function whereas the second one is even over the symmetric interval $[-1,1]$. Hence the first integral is zero and the second one is twice the integral over $[0,1]$ (where $|u|=u$). So, it remains to evaluate
$$I=3\cdot 2\int_{0}^1e^{u}\cos\left(\dfrac{u}{2}\right) du.$$
Can you take it from here?